# Lumen - Locales File Location

Tags: php, laravel, api, localization, lumen

in Laravel I can easly find the locales files in /resources/langs/{en, es, fr}

I'm searching the same in Lumen, so I can change validation errors or make custom errors.

Thank you all for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Lumen doesn't have a locale files but you can add them easily in `/resources/langs/{locale}` and you can use helper function `trans('file.key')`